# Parametric equation of a curve: a line in a circle transform to a curve in an ellipse

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Giving the circle with a line segment inside, if the circle was stretched into an ellipse, what is the parametric equation of the parabolic curve (I assume) transformed from the line segment?
[circle to ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2Fkg.jpg)

I want the curve as in shown in the pic. Scaling axis only give the line segment with a new slope. I could draw the curve by interpolated the line according to the displacement field inside the circle, but I don't know the parametric equation of the curve. Could anyone give me some hints how to determine the equation in trigonometric way?

Comment: "I could draw the curve by interpolated the line according to the displacement field inside the circle" Please give more details. What is the displacement field inside the circle? Do you have a concrete formula for it?

Answer (score 3):

The stretch in question is a linear transformation, so lines go to lines.

Moreover, horizontal lines go to horizontal lines, and vertical lines go to vertical lines.

The line $x=c\;$goes to the line $x=c'$, where $c'$ satisfies
$$\frac{c'}{a}=\frac{c}{r}$$
hence the new line is $x=c\bigl({\large{\frac{a}{r}}}\bigr)$.

Comment: With linear transformation I would get a line. But I do want the curve as as interpolated the area in circle to the area in the ellipse. What I did is find the displacement vector field from the circle's boundary to the ellipse's boundary and interpolate the vector field inside the boundary. With this interpolated vector field, I could have the curve (parabolic shape) from the line but I don't know how to determine it's parametric equation.

Comment: but thank for the answer :)

Comment: if possible, how to determine the curve without the interpolation? I have not idea.

Comment: @J. AM: Can you edit your question to make clear how your "stretch" is defined? A few numerical examples with input point $(x,y)$, and corresponding output point $(x',y')$ would help clarify the nature of the intended transformation.

Answer (score 1):

How do you define your  *stretch transformation?* In any transformation a relation between variables before and after transformation is defined.

Setting a variable in one system to a constant we can map the curve in the other system. Like eg polar to cartesian coordinates $ r=a \rightarrow x^2+y^2= a^2. $

I could not figure out transfomation relations in your question. Are any lengths conserved?

Setting aside a full approach if we proceed just with the relation you gave that automatically defines and additionally could take care of its relation to the circle:

$$ x = a \cos \theta + c,$$

by converting to polar coordinates we get directly (no parametrization) the curve Conchoid of Nichomedes:

$$ r  \cos \theta   = a \cos \theta + c \,;  \quad r= a + c \cdot \sec \theta, $$

where the unit circle is added for comparision. For the curve graph $ (a=1, c= 0.3 ) .$

As stated above the strectch definition has still to be looked into.

[image: Conch Nichomedes]